# why map function give undefined while iteration?

Tags: javascript

```
const a=[{name:'ee'},{name:"ddsf"}]
const b=a.map(({name})=>{
  if(name!='ee')
  return {
    key:'dd',
    name:name +'sss'
  }
})

console.log(b)
```

I am getting

```
[undefined, [object Object] {
  key: "dd",
  name: "ddsfsss"
}]
```

why  **undefined** ?

**Expected output**

```
[[object Object] {
  key: "dd",
  name: "ddsfsss"
}]
```

here is code
https://jsbin.com/wujekavivo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Because you return nothing if name is equal to ee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function returns an array that has correspondence with the array you iterate to. So the `undefined` value corresponds to the first item in the array with `name: 'ee'`. If you just want to get those with name !== 'ee', you can just use `filter` instead. Or better yet you can do:

```
a.reduce((arr, {name}) => {
  if(name === 'ee') {
    arr.push({
      key: 'dd',
      name: name + 'sss',
    });
  }
  return arr;
}, []);
```

Unlike `map`, `reduce` you pretty much have more control.

Answer (score 1):

You want `.filter` before `.map`.

```
const b = a.filter(o => o.name != 'ee')
  .map(o => ({
      key: 'dd',
      name: o.name + 'sss'
    })
  );
```

This is because `.map` always returns an array of length equal to the original. By filtering first, you're reducing it down to the desired set.

You can also use `.reduce()` to accomplish both at once.

```
const b = a.reduce((o, acc) => 
    o.name == 'ee' ? acc : acc.concat({
      key: 'dd',
      name: o.name + 'sss'
    })
, []);
```